# Parsing weather XML data in Swift

Tags: xml, swift, swift3, xml-parsing, weather

I'm new to webservices and trying to parse some xml data received from a weather site. This structure is different to me than other xml data that openweathermap api returns. How should I handle these nodes and tuplelist to match the values of all parameters in DataRecord? One parameter like 'Temperature' has several repeating values..

```
<gml:rangeSet>
<gml:DataBlock>
<gml:rangeParameters/>
<gml:doubleOrNilReasonTupleList>
113.01 20.03 1013.89 53.37 234.0 4.38 2.44 3.64 6.28 8.76 6.81 35.1 2.0 30.2 10.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 6852076.5 6429906.5 -1344119.25 6131957.5 3122299.25 113.01 19.16 1014.14 59.56 223.0 3.59 1.36 3.31 6.28 6.94 8.23 80.0 3.0 64.9 10.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 7114915.5 7732196.5 -1553170.88 6363484.0 3291196.5 113.01 17.73 1014.33 69.87 209.0 3.05 0.45 3.04 3.56 5.8 10.15 11.9 1.0 6.8 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 7158493.5 8958460.0 -1820905.13 6399564.5 3334774.5 113.01 16.32 1014.4 80.78 197.0 2.91 -0.19 2.91 3.55 5.47 11.8 55.5 2.0 0.0 0.0 51.2 0.0 0.0 7158493.5 10136144.0 -2121490.0 6399564.5 3334774.5 113.01 15.71 1014.52 88.46 199.0 3.37 -0.01 3.37 3.55 6.52 13.11 100.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 100.0 0.0 0.0 7155351.5 11316823.0 -2407310.5 6400342.0 3335817.5 113.01 15.17 1014.64 93.19 199.0 2.99 -0.12 3.01 3.55 5.91 13.68 88.9 3.0 0.6 0.0 94.9 0.0 0.0 7156596.5 12520698.0 -2668392.5 6399287.5 3332406.25 113.01 14.4 1014.3 97.24 189.0 2.25 -0.52 2.19 3.56 4.26 13.81 90.6 3.0 18.9 8.9 90.6 0.0 0.0 7158433.0 13713832.0 -2929743.0 6398189.5 3334714.25
</gml:doubleOrNilReasonTupleList>
</gml:DataBlock>
</gml:rangeSet>
<gml:coverageFunction>
<gml:CoverageMappingRule>
<gml:ruleDefinition>Linear</gml:ruleDefinition>
</gml:CoverageMappingRule>
</gml:coverageFunction>
<gmlcov:rangeType>
<swe:DataRecord>
<swe:field name="GeopHeight" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=GeopHeight&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="Temperature" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=Temperature&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="Pressure" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=Pressure&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="Humidity" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=Humidity&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="WindDirection" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=WindDirection&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="WindSpeedMS" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=WindSpeedMS&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="WindUMS" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=WindUMS&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="WindVMS" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=WindVMS&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="MaximumWind" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=MaximumWind&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="WindGust" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=WindGust&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="DewPoint" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=DewPoint&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="TotalCloudCover" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=TotalCloudCover&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="WeatherSymbol3" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=WeatherSymbol3&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="LowCloudCover" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=LowCloudCover&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="MediumCloudCover" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=MediumCloudCover&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="HighCloudCover" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=HighCloudCover&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="Precipitation1h" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=Precipitation1h&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="PrecipitationAmount" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=PrecipitationAmount&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="RadiationGlobalAccumulation" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=RadiationGlobalAccumulation&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="RadiationLWAccumulation" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=RadiationLWAccumulation&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="RadiationNetSurfaceLWAccumulation" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=RadiationNetSurfaceLWAccumulation&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="RadiationNetSurfaceSWAccumulation" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=RadiationNetSurfaceSWAccumulation&language=eng"/>
<swe:field name="RadiationDiffuseAccumulation" xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&param=RadiationDiffuseAccumulation&language=eng"/>
</swe:DataRecord>
</gmlcov:rangeType>
</gmlcov:MultiPointCoverage>
</om:result>
```

Comment: Are there any particular reasons that justify using this XML service when countless JSON alternatives exist?

Comment: Use NSXMLParser.

Comment: Yes it is country specific and that local weather site doesn't have an api instead offer open data. They have implementations in Catalog Service for Web (CSW), Web Map Service (WMS) and Web Feature Service (WFS)

Comment: @ElTomato: it's called `XMLParser` now.